# How to make a ViewModel for an anonymous type from a linq query

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, model-view-controller

I have joined and grouped 2 databases using linq in my controller, and now I need to parse it to the view. I know, I gonna need a ViewModel to do it, but I have no clue what to put in it, to make it work.

My Linq query in the controller looks like this:

```cs
var energyUsageViewModel = 
    from e in applicationDbContext
    join u in _context.UsagesPerMonth on e.Id equals u.EnergyUsageId into u2
    group u2 by new { Year = e.Year }
    into u3
    select u3.ToList();
return View(energyUsageViewModel);
```

In short what the linq query does is taking the "year" from table "e" joining it with table "u" which contains the energy usage per month, which I am gonna use to make a table in my view, which displays the year and usage per month in one row.

And currently my ViewModel looks like this (obviously not working):

```cs
public class EnergyUsageViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<UsagePerMonth> UsagePerMonthVm { get; set; }
}
```

The view takes a model of:

```
@model IEnumerable<Jullerup.Models.EnergyUsageViewModel>
```

I have tried to modify the ViewModel to take u3, but haven't succeeded.
I get the following invalid operation exception:

> InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'System.Linq.Enumerable+SelectEnumerableIterator`2[System.Linq.IGrouping`2[<>f__AnonymousType10`1[System.String],System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Jullerup.Models.UsagePerMonth]],System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Jullerup.Models.UsagePerMonth]]]', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Jullerup.Models.EnergyUsageViewModel]'.

How do I edit my ViewModel to handle u3?

Update:
I'm working with 3 classes.
Customer class:

```
public class Customer
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }

        //Navigation Prop
        public ICollection<EnergyUsage>? energyUsage { get; set; }
    }
```

EnergyUsage class:

```
 public class EnergyUsage
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int CustomerID { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public int YearlyHeatUsage { get; private set; }
        public List<UsagePerMonth> UsagePerYear { get; set; }
      
        //Navigation Prop
        public Customer? Customer { get; set; }     
    }
```

UsagePerMonth class:

```
 public class UsagePerMonth
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public MonthEnum Month { get; set; }
        public int Usage { get; set; }
        public int HeatUsage { get; private set; }
        public string EnergyType { get; set; }
        private EnergyMeasurement energyType { get; set; }
        public int EnergyUsageId { get; set; }
    }
```

In the database Customer.Id (PK) has a one to many relationship to EnergyUsage.CustomerId (FK) and EnergyUsage.Id (PK) has a one to many relationship to UsagePerMonth.EnergyUsageId (FK).
What I am trying to do, is to get an object/list something I can use in the view to display all instances of UsagePerMonth grouped by Customer.Year for a certain Customer.Id.

Comment: You do not need ViewModel if you are not intending to take any additional property. change your model type as actual type of energyUsageViewModel. or else cast your list to a type of List<Jullerup.Models.EnergyUsageViewModel>.

Comment: @RajeshG I do add an extra property "Year", because I need it for grouping.

Comment: Then, as I mentioned cast your list to correct type before passing it to the view.

Comment: Why do you perform grouping? What is `UsagePerMonth`, show class definition.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I have updated the question, but in short I need it sorted by year.

Comment: @RajeshG My problem is that I don't understand what "the right type" is.

Comment: your right type is type of your model used in view which is `IEnumerable<Jullerup.Models.EnergyUsageViewModel>`. Possibly try `.ToList<EnergyUsageViewModel>()` instead of generic `.ToList()`. It is all explained in your error statement, read it carefully.

Comment: @RajeshG I still get the same error though. When I use  `.ToList<EnergyUsageViewModel>()` instead I get a error on my select:
`Error CS1942: The type of the expression in the select clause is incorrect.  Type inference failed in the call to 'Select'.`